# Get top level page parent title

Tags: pages, hierarchical

How do I get the page title of the upper most parent page of the page the visitor is currently on?

Let me describe:

I have this page structure:

- Example Title 1

  - Example Title 1-1

    - Example Title 1-1-1
    - Example Title 1-1-2
  - Example Title 1-2
- Example Title 2
- Example Title 3
- Example Title 4

Here is what I want to return:

- User is on `Example Title 1` return `Example Title 1`
- User is on `Example Title 1-1` return `Example Title 1`
- User is on `Example Title 1-1-1` return `Example Title 1`
- User is on `Example Title 2` return `Example Title 2`

Normally what I would do is check `$post->parent` and if `0` then return page title else return title of page above. Problem is that $post->parent will only go back one level. I need to use some sort of recursive function that keeps going back until `$post->parent == 0`.

Now I can manage this myself but the only way I could think of doing it would be to use get_post() each time but imagine I'm 8 layers deep (we need to go deeper). That would involve loading 8 pages to finally get to the top level. Anyone have a better way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found this way:

```
if ( 0 == $post->post_parent ) {
    the_title();
} else {
    $parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
    echo apply_filters( "the_title", get_the_title( end ( $parents ) ) );
}
```

Anyone got a better way please answer.

Comment: That's probably about as good as any. One other way would be to loop iteratively through `get_page( array( 'post_parent' => $post->post_parent ) )` until you get to the top of the hierarchy. Your approach would clearly be more efficient.

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit. (+1)

Comment: I know this is old, but as it provides an array (even if there's only one ancestor), doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if its the efficient this can be done via `recursive function`

```
function get_post_ancestor_title($post_id){
    $post = get_post($post_id)->post_parent;
    if ( 0 == $post->post_parent ) {
       return get_the_title();
    } else {
       get_post_ancestor_title($post->ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Better this way: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/find-id-of-top-most-parent-page/