# Setting Up "Split Site" Navigation in Wordpress

Tags: navigation

I'm currently attempting to set up a WordPress install for an organization which has two separate devisions. I'm having a very hard time wrapping my mind around how to create two navigation menus and reliably switch between them based on the currently viewed content.

I can't use multiple WordPress installs, as content will be shared in some cases and a single dashboard is preferred.

I tried using categories, but pages can't be assigned to a category. I tried using page parents, but posts can't be assigned a parent.

I'd like the solution to allow non-technical people to maintain both navigations easily.

How can I achieve this?

Related questions:

- [Different menu navigation per category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121268/different-menu-navigation-per-category)
- [Get top level page parent title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32072/get-top-level-page-parent-title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use categories with pages, via [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type), but if you were to use a taxonomy for this, it may be better to [register a custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) specifically for that purpose.

Another option is to [add a meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and provide simple means of selecting a menu, which would be saved and accessed via post meta data, otherwise known as [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Milo! I'm actually second-guessing the whole premise now. I may not worry about forcing posts to do the same thing as pages. Anyway, I'll keep this info in mind should I decide to continue down that path.

Comment: Four months later, and post launch, we ended up going with using categories. That way posts can be in one, both, or no sections, and its categories can be referenced to determine what navigation should be shown. None or both selected, and the main site navigation is shown. One selected, and the appropriate division's navigation is shown.